# How to catch 2 PlatformException errors ( Flutter )

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have 2 PlatformException errors one is ( The email address is badly formatted ) the other is ( The email address is already in use by another account ) , i know how to catch one of them using (
on PlatformException catch (err) {} catch (err) {} ) but how can i catch them both?

Comment: If they are both `PlatformException` then `on PlatformException catch (e)` will catch them both. Also, never do a blanket `catch (e)` as that will hide all sorts of subtle errors that you should be catching and handling individually.

Comment: Which error is it originated from? Sounds like an Exception from a package right, not from the Flutter SDK

Comment: @Bach yes it's an exception from FireBaseAuth package ( Sign up method )

Comment: @Abion47 may god forgive you (: i got stuck trying for 4 hours because you told me to never do a blanket catch ( e ) but when i added it it worked lol, anyways thanks for the help!

Comment: @kingstation99 No, the point is that you don't do it because it's one of those easy-to-use and easy-to-abuse solutions. Using a blanket catch might work, but you now have a place in your code where if anything goes wrong, you will never know unless it causes something else to go wrong, and then you will spend hours tracking down the source rather than your app crashing and you immediately know where and why. I didn't say to not use it because it won't work, I said to not use it because it's a terrible and lazy habit to get into and a bad practice overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add an if condition inside the

```dart
on PlatformException catch (err) {}
```

and compare the err.code ,err.message or err.details, depending on where the message you are looking for is

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. but i need to add that you have to make the code like this :  on PlatformException catch (err) {} catch (err) {   }   and you put your if condition inside the second catch err or it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the `PlatformException` with one `catch` and then check the error code:

```dart
try {
  ...
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  switch (e.code) {
    case 'ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD':
      ...
      break;
    case 'ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND':
      ...
      break;
    default:
      ...
  }
}
```